# What happens if I use the 110v (US) electric toothbrush charger on 220v (South East Asia)

Tags: charging

I accidentally charged one cycle and the toothbrush still works. But is it safe to use it in this voltage? What's the effect on the battery? Does it charge in half voltage or is there any in built voltage regulation?

[image: electric toothbrush charger]

Comment: I washed my coloured clothes at 100 degC so will I still be able to wear them or will they have shrunk or will they rapidly deteriorate over time?

Comment: Wondering why they had to add "Personal Hygiene Appliance"..

Comment: @Trevor_G about as much a waste of time as adding the voltage rating or so it seems.

Comment: @Andyaka or the ubiquitous "May contain nuts" on a bag of peanuts....

Comment: @Trevor_G sounds like a description of SE.EE

Answer (score 1):

This will fry the magnetic coil from twice the excitation voltage and possible saturate the core and melt it.  try it out and post the Youtube video for proof of concept (j/k);)  It will be far more than twice the temperature rise when the inductance (reactance) drops to just the wire resistance.

I suspect the small gauge wire inside will self-fuse.

It reminds me when in 1970 when my older brother borrowed a $5k portable tape recorder from CBC and **smoked it** on 230Vac during his trip thru Africa with a Land Rover.  ( He majored in Political Science not engineering)

### added

> However consider the very low VA rating of this device, it would be  perfect candidate for a 2:1 stepdown voltage transformer inside a USA bathroom junction box and receptacle for shavers and toothbrushes alike that run off 120Vac.
>   [image]
>   Although with the price of e-toothbrushes, it may be a thing of the past.

Comment: "He majored in Political Science " Well, he had lots of "smoke" to go around then.. ;D

Comment: It's made in Germany. It probably won't catch fire.

Comment: It may not have a coil though Tony, it's a charger and may be just a simple AC-DC convertor. Still, it will likely fail, and isolation maybe compromised.

Comment: It is Braun's first Wireless magnetic charger with 50% efficiency and low power.  Its just a transformer with the toothbrush having the secondary winding.  I know these products.

Comment: A family lady friend banjaxed her husband's shaver. She reckoned that  110 V was for ladies and 230 V for men. (By that reckoning "real men" probably need 400 V.)

Comment: Thankfully, The toothbrush is charging, And working fine so far. That's why I was wondering what really happens at charging? does it charge with lower voltage?  And whether to keep using this way?

Comment: So you are applying 230V~/50Hz when it is rated for 110-130V~50/60Hz  Then twice the V is being applied to Primary and Secondary must decide how to regulate perhaps by DC Vref then temperature